# NetworkStream.read taking 2 seconds to read data from stream (TCP C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, streamreader

I have a TCP request response model in C# where I am communicating with a server. Once the server has written data to the stream, I am reading that data. But `stream.read` is taking 2 seconds to read the data. I need to send an explicit acknowledgement to the server, within 2 seconds but am unable to do so because of the time taken to read the data.
Below is my code to read data:

```
            byte[] resp = new byte[100000];
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            int bytes;

            String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("Before reading data: ");
            Console.WriteLine(timeStamp);

            do
            {
                bytes = stream.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes);
                               
            }
            while (bytes > 0);

            timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("After reading data: ");
            Console.WriteLine(timeStamp);

            
            GenerateAcknowledgemnt(stream);


            timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("After sending ack: ");
            Console.WriteLine(timeStamp);
```

Below are the timestamps read, in the format yyyyMMddHHmmssff:

Before reading data:
202205061549**08**17

After reading data:
202205061549**10**19

After sending ack:
202205061549**10**20

I have highlighted the seconds bold.

How do I reduce the time that `stream.read` is taking to read? I have tried to wrap the network stream in a BufferedStream as well, but it didn't help.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to use raw tcp streams? Some message-oriented protocol would probably be easier to use and should handle problems like this.

Comment: It is a tcp request response model, I would need to use tcp streams.

Comment: Need to see the code server side.  But first try changing your while to use `stream.DataAvailable` instead of `bytes > 0`.

Comment: Taking a stab here: if you can try to use ReadAsync to ensure you are not blocking threads, further if possible rather use CopyToAsync to move your data to the MemoryStream

Comment: @Zer0 there are almost no scenarios where checking `DataAvailable` is the right solution; the *only* time that is usually relevant is to choose between sync vs async IO, and even then it usually isn't worth it, since if you're *open to* async IO, the async API can always just complete synchronously if there is data available

Comment: @MarcGravell Never said it was the right solution.  But Read returning 0 is typically socket closed.  DataAvailable will return false even with socket open.  That said, yes, using async, IMO, is always better but if the code can handle receiving "partial" data then it works fine.  Although without message framing I don't see how this would ever work.  Granted that makes "partial" messages moot.  Bottom line there's many problems here so fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you are performing a read loop that keeps going until `Read` returns a non-positive number; in TCP, this means you are waiting until the other end *hangs up* (or at least hangs up their outbound socket) until you get out of that loop. I suspect what is happening is that the other end is *giving up on you*, closing their connection, and only then do you get out of the loop.

Basically: you can't loop like that; instead, what you need to do is to *carefully* read until *either* EOF (`bytes <= 0`) *or* until you have at least one complete frame that you can respond to, and in the latter case: respond *then*. This usually means a loop more like (pseudo-code):

```
while (TryReadSomeMoreData()) // performs a read into the buffer, positive result
{
    // note: may have more than one frame per successful 'read'
    while (TryParseOneFrame(out frame)) 
    {
        ProcessFrame(frame); // includes sending responses
        // (and discard anything that you've now processed from the back-buffer)
    }
}
```

(parsing a frame here means: following whatever rules apply about isolating a single message from the stream - this may mean looking for a sentinel value such as CR/LF/NUL, or may mean checking if you have enough bytes to read a header that includes a length, and then checking that you have however-many bytes the header indicates as the payload)

This is a *little* awkward if you're using `MemoryStream` as the backlog, as the discard step is not convenient; the "pipelines" API is more specifically designed for this, but: either way can work.

Secondly: you may prefer async IO, although sync IO is probably fine for a simple client application with only one connection (but not for servers, which may have many many connections).

Comment: thanks! I used readAsync and it worked!

Comment: read-async by itself isn't a magic fix here; that ... suggests that it is now working for the wrong reasons :/